# Read all entries in a table and save it to MapState in Flink only once

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql, flink-statefun

I have a table `Metadata`.

I want the contents of the table in my Flink application. So I want to read all entries in the table and save to `MapState<Metadata::Id, Metadata>`.

If my application restarts, I do not want to read from table, instead, I will read from `MapState<Metadata::Id, Metadata>` and use it.

Is there a way I can achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

The youtube video and github repo I linked to in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60638922/2000823) cover a number of similar scenarios. But the best way to bootstrap Flink state is to preload the data into a savepoint using the [State Processor API](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/libs/state_processor_api.html).

Keep in mind that Flink's `MapState` is a kind of key-partitioned state. So if you use `MapState<Metadata::Id, Metadata>`, that is effectively a `Map<KEY, MapState<Metadata::Id, Metadata>>` that is sharded across the cluster by KEY.

Here's an example showing how to create a savepoint containing a `ValueState<Integer>`:

```java
public class Bootstrap {
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
        ExecutionEnvironment bEnv =
                ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        BootstrapTransformation<Integer> transform =
                OperatorTransformation.bootstrapWith(bEnv.fromElements(1, 2, 3))
                        .keyBy(String::valueOf)
                        .transform(new SimplestTransform());

        Savepoint
                .create(new FsStateBackend("file:///tmp/checkpoints"), 256)
                .withOperator("my-operator-uid", transform)
                .write("file:///tmp/savepoints/");

        bEnv.execute();
    }

    static public class SimplestTransform
            extends KeyedStateBootstrapFunction<String, Integer> {
        ValueState<Integer> state;

        @Override
        public void open(Configuration parameters) {
            ValueStateDescriptor<Integer> descriptor = new
                    ValueStateDescriptor<>("total", Types.INT);
            state = getRuntimeContext().getState(descriptor);
        }

        @Override
        public void processElement(Integer value, Context ctx) throws Exception {
            state.update(value);
        }
    }
}
```

This creates a sharded key/value map containing `{"1": 1, "2": 2, "3": 3}`.